# Why isn't this character-counter program not altering the list?

Tags: python, list, graph, count

I'm writting a program to that counts the number of times each letter appears in a text.
I'm trying to convert that into a graph, by print out the bar graph line by line. Slowly adding the space above the letter when the countdown reaches the # of times it appears.

```
import string
n=input("Enter Text, I wish you luck:")
list1=[]            #Empty List
list2=list(" "*26)  #26 space list
for a in string.ascii_uppercase:#from a-z
    n1=n.count(a)               #counts letters
    list1.append(n1)            #appends numbers
    m=max(list1)                #finds most occuring letter
c=m+1
while c!=0:                 
    c=c-1
    if c==0:
        print(string.ascii_uppercase)
        break
    for x in list1:             #suppose to check every term in list1
        if x >c:                #x is greater than countdowner
            k=list1.index(x)    #find term number
            list2[k]="*"        #replace blank with "*"
        elif x==c:
            #if x is equal to countdowner
            k=list1.index(x)    #find term number
            list2[k]="*"        #replaces that term place in list2
    print(''.join(list2))
```

The code only accepts uppercase letters, and right now it only add letters to the countdown list one at a time. So when count reaches one appearance, and 3 letters appear once, it will only print a * on top of one of those letter.

Sample input: HELLO STACKOVERFLOW

```
           *              
    *      *              
*   *      *                            
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `k=list1.index(x)` can only find the first occurrence of `x` in `list1`. So you could put a loop here, using the extended form of `index()`:

`list1.index(x, start, end)`

which only looks for an index that lies in the range(start, end)

The loop would have to contain a `try: ... except` block to handle the `ValueError` exception.

But there's another way to handle this.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from string import ascii_uppercase

def bargraph(data):
    data = data.upper()
    print(data)
    print(''.join(sorted(list(data))))

    #Count number of occurences of each letter in data
    counts = [data.count(a) for a in ascii_uppercase]

    #A single row of the bar graph, initially full of spaces
    row = list(" " * 26)

    for c in range(max(counts), 0, -1):
        for k in range(26):
            if counts[k] == c:
                row[k] = "*"

        print(''.join(row))

    print(ascii_uppercase)

def main():
    #data = input("Enter Text, I wish you luck:")
    data = "This is a test string for the bar graph function"
    bargraph(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My version of your program converts the string to upper case, prints it, and then sorts it and prints it again to make it easier to check that the bar printing section is doing what it's supposed to do.

It uses a list comprehension to build the list of character counts. It can be made even shorter by using a list comprehension to construct `row`.

```
def bargraph(data):
    data = data.upper()
    print(data)
    print(''.join(sorted(list(data))))

    #Count number of occurences of each letter in data
    counts = [data.count(a) for a in ascii_uppercase]

    for c in range(max(counts), 0, -1):
        print(''.join(["*" if counts[k] >= c else " " for k in range(26)]))

    print(ascii_uppercase)
```

**output** for both versions :)

```
THIS IS A TEST STRING FOR THE BAR GRAPH FUNCTION
         AAABCEEFFGGHHHIIIINNNOOPRRRRSSSSTTTTTTU
                   *      
                   *      
        *        ***      
*      **    *   ***      
*   *****    **  ***      
*** *****    *** ****     
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

---

**edit**

I should mention that there's a more efficient way to count the occurrences of each letter. The current method has to scan through the data string 26 times, once for each letter. That's a bit inefficient, especially if there's a lot of data to process. So it's better to just scan through the data once, and accumulate the counts. One way to do that is to use a dict.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from string import ascii_uppercase

def bargraph(data):
    data = data.upper()
    print(data)
    print(''.join(sorted(list(data))))

    #Count number of occurences of each letter in data
    counts = dict(zip(ascii_uppercase, 26*(0,)))
    for c in data:
        if c.isupper():
            counts[c] += 1
    highcount = max(counts.values())

    for c in range(highcount, 0, -1):
        print(''.join([" *"[counts[k] >= c] for k in ascii_uppercase]))

    print(ascii_uppercase)

def main():
    #data = input("Enter Text, I wish you luck:")
    data = "This is a test string for the bar graph function"
    bargraph(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've also used a little trick to make the row printing step even more compact.

`counts[k] >= c` will either be `False` or `True`.

But Python lets us use boolean values as if they were `int` values, with `False` == 0 and `True` == 1.

Thus `" *"[counts[k] >= c]` results in `" "` if `counts[k] >= c` is `False`, and `"*"` if it's `True`.